# How to decode Base64 String to png/jpg

Tags: groovy, soapui

```
def prop = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Kundendaten").getPropertyValue("phototandata")
//log.info( "Photo TAN property value= "+prop)

Base64 decoder = new Base64();
byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decode(prop);
FileOutputStream osf = new FileOutputStream(new File("B:\\Transfer\\haoot\\bild"));
osf.write(imgBytes);
osf.flush();
```

> [No signature of method :java .util.Base64.decode() is applicale for
> argument type error

Comment: How is this related to "SOAP"?  For base64 decoding see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html (so its. `Base64.decoder.decode(...)`

Comment: This error string looks incomplete, could you please provide the whole?

Answer (score 0):

```
Base64 decoder = new Base64();
byte[] imgBytes = decoder.getDecoder().decode(prop);
```